# Failing to connect to Database due to database in recovery

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008, developer edition. I connect to my database from my asp.net mvc application using Linq2SQL. I noticed that my database went into recovery mode about 4 times in a span of a month. I am running a few complext Linq2SQL queries. When database is in recovery mode, my asp.net mvc application is going off line as it could not connect to the database. I do not know how to prevent the database from getting into recovery mode. I have seen some of the questions on SO, but could not find a way how to solve it. I am hoping some one could help me out.

Comment: Is it just selects or are u you inserting/updating/deleting ?

Comment: Serverfault? I don't think any code or query is putting your db in recovery mode.

Comment: @used2could, it is only selector queries. they are all linq2sql queries, generated automatically

Comment: You should take a look at SQL Server logs, try logs at event viewer and check out the logs folder inside your SQL Server installation directory. If you find some error in these logs, show us here.

Comment: Every few seconds (30 to 80 sec) later, i see a message Starting up database 'MyDatabase'. After that I see "Recovery completed for database 'MyDatabase' (database ID 31) in 1 second(s) (analysis 187 ms<c/> redo 0 ms<c/> undo 1022". Can you please see whether anything is wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some possibilities/things to check include:

- Is this database part of a Log
  Shipping configuration? If so, whilst
  the Secondary server is being
  restored you will be unable to
  establish connections to the
  database.
- You are certain you are using the Developer
  Edition of SQL Server and not the
  Express Edition?
- Is the Autoclose option set to TRUE?
  If so the database will shutdown when
  there are no active user connections.

To check if you have any databases set to Autoclose use the following T-SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE DATABASEPROPERTYEX(name, 'IsAutoClose') = 1
```

Comment: I am using the developer edition of SQL Server 2008.
I found that IsAutoClose is set to 1 for my database. I understood what this AutoClose means. You think this could be the reason?

Comment: @mohang: AUTOCLOSE being set to TRUE(1) was 100% the reason for your issue. Glad you have now resolved things.